# How to getting image file URL from a folder inside web project(WebContent/images/isilog.gif)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Directory Structure

> MYProjectName
>      
> WebContent(Folder)
>          
> -Images (Folder) 
> --isilog.gif

/*Below is my code. I have taken image from WebContent as static.
I want to take it dynamically from images folder. */

```
public class ABC {
public static final String DEST = "G://HRS Barcode/ISILOGO.pdf";
public static final String IMG = "D://MyFolder Workplace/MYProjectName/WebContent/images/isilog.gif";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new ABC().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    OutputStream out = null;
    Document document = new Document();
    Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(432, 288);
    document.setPageSize(pageSize);
    document.setMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
    out = new FileOutputStream(DEST);
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

    document.open();

    document.setMarginMirroringTopBottom(true);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidths(new int[] { 2, 7 });
    Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT); // ALIGN_BASELINE
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell("XYZ company Ltd");
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    document.add(table);
    LineSeparator separator = new LineSeparator();
    Chunk linebreak = new Chunk(separator);
    document.add(linebreak);
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Document Generated...!!!!!!");
    writer.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The simple way you can load your image from the images folder of your project is use this simple 1 line of code.(Try your URL's accordingly)

**Way 1:**

```
File sourceimage = new File("D://MyFolder Workplace/MYProjectName/WebContent/images/isilog.gif");
Image image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
```

**Way 2:**

```
  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/isilog.jpg"));
```

If You want to know further, you can always look into the documentation.
Here is the [link to Reading/Loading an Image using java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: @ Tahir sir ,I got exception  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! at the line IMG1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/isilogo.gif"));

Comment: I added a new answer. Check way 1. This will definitely solve your issue. and if this is the correct answer. Then don't forget to accept my answer.  @PNayak

Comment: @PNayak Hey! Did you check my answer?

Comment: sir, I also done what ever you mentioned ..I will to be wants dynamic didn't want to  mention drive name like D://MyFolder Workplace.. It to be taken as project path dynamic  at the run time. i,e "/WebContent/images/isilog.gif"

Comment: I will add that solution later. If this worked. You can accept my answer. @PNayak

Answer (score 0):

Usually the images are put in a separate folder.
It seems like you have the images in the right folder already. If you don't want to use a static path you can use this relative path: "images/isilogo.gif".
This way the picture can be accessed by the application no matter where you execute it.

Comment: Then he can access it the way I told him to.

Comment: It's the right answer and instead of telling me I'm wrong tell us what the right answer is then